# Scala: Can't catch exception thrown inside a closure

Tags: exception, scala, closures

Disclaimer: absolute novice in Scala :(

I have the following defined:

```
def tryAndReport(body: Unit) : Unit = {
  try {
    body
  } catch {
    case e: MySpecificException => doSomethingUseful
  }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
tryAndReport{
  someCodeThatThrowsMySpecificException()
}
```

While the call to someCodeThatThrowsMySpecificException happens just fine, the exception is not being caught in tryAndReport.

Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing body from `Unit` to `=> Unit`. The way its defined now, it considers `body` a block of code to evaluate to `Unit`. Using call-by-name, it will be executed in the `try` as defined and *should* be caught.

Answer (score 6):

The `body` in your `tryAndReport` method is not a closure or block, it's a value (of type `Unit`).

I don't recommend using a by-name argument, but rather an explicit function.

```
def tryAndReport(block: () => Unit): Unit = {
  try { block() }
  catch { case e: MSE => dSU }
}
```

Comment: *I don't recommend using a by-name argument, but rather an explicit function.* -- Why?

Comment: I second that, you shouldn't give a recommandation like that without a rationale.

Comment: Because I believe in saying what you mean. You want the function evaluated within the body of the `tryAndReport`, that should not be hidden behind a by-name parameter.